# can I search github marketplace for actions with a filter for certified actions

Tags: github, github-actions, action

I am looking for actions on github marketplace:
https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions

and I want to only use github certified actions. Is it possible to filter my search queries for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "certified action", only action from legit organization (creator verified by Github with blue stick on marketplace)

[image: https://miro.medium.com/max/486/1*b7hyw8oy4B2OASxuxvQDAQ.png]

You can filter those with:

https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&verification=verified_creator

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is exactly what I wanted. Also thanks for clarifying that "certified" is not the correct term but rather "verified_creator" is what I am looking for. I got the word "certified" from this warning label that is common on many actions from unverified organizations:

Nexus Repository Publisher for GitHub Actions is not certified by GitHub. It is provided by a third-party and is governed by separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support documentation.